# Transform map into bytes

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

I have the map:

```
%{ HEADER: "000000000 000000000000 00000000 ", 
   AM01: %{"C4" => "11111111", "C5" => "1"}, 
   AM04: %{"C2" => "22222222", "C6" => "2"} 
}
```

How can I transform this map into bytes like this:

```
"\x02\x1e000000000 000000000000 00000000 \x1e\x1cAM01\x1cC411111111\x1cC51\x1e\x1cAM04\x1cC222222222\x1cC62\x03"
```

so far I've reached that point, but the end result is a list.

```
for segment <- %{AM03: %{"DB" => "1"}, AM04: %{"C2" => "1"}, AM06: %{"CR" => " "}}, into: [] do
  {name, fields} = segment                                                                    
  for field <- fields, into: [] do                                                                      
    {field_name, field_value} = field                                                                          
    "\x1e\x1c#{name}\x1c#{field_name}\x1c#{field_value}"
  end
end
```

there I ask: 1 - Is this a functional form? 2 - How do I give an Enum.join () on the output of this for?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: the truth is that I do not know the correct way to do this in elixir. I come from object-oriented programming and my code looks like this

Comment: Are the `AM01` and `AM04` etc. values supposed to be sorted? Map keys are unsorted, so you will need to sort  the map before serializing if that's the case.

Comment: What could go wrong with just calling `Enum.join/1` on the result? Note that `"\x1e\x1c" == <<30, 28>> #⇒ true` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Kerenl.SpecialForm.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension supports collecting into binary out of the box:

```rb
input = %{AM03: %{"DB" => "1"},
          AM04: %{"C2" => "1"},
          AM06: %{"CR" => " "}}

for {name, value} <- input, {fldn, fldv} <- value,
  into: <<>>,
  do: "\x1e\x1c#{name}\x1c" <> fldn <> "\x1c" <> fldv  

#⇒ <<30, 28, 65, 77, 48, 51, ..., 82, 28, 32>>
```